# How to create a windows cmd script to rename files

Tags: command-line, prompt, ms-dos

I have a bunch of files named YYYYDDMM_prep888 and I want to rename them to YYYYMMDD_prep888, just exchanging DD for MM. I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted yourself or do you just want some one to do your work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your files have a regular form you can use a similar batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F %%A IN ('dir /b *_prep888') DO (
    rem split the data
    set file=%%A
    set pre=!file:~0,4!
    set dd=!file:~4,2!
    set mm=!file:~6,2!
    set post=!file:~8,8!
    set new_name=!pre!!mm!!dd!!post!

    ECHO renaming !file! into !new_name!

    ren !file! !new_name!
)
```